# Param value truncates at first space (rest of URL gone)

Tags: html, perl, cgi

**Problem**

I have an html form and a perl cgi.pm script.

A search is entered into a text field. If there is a space in the entry, any other parameters(like selected radio buttons) are cut off. ex. 'hello world', results in **only** 'hello'.

So the url has the value: `query=hello` instead of `query=hello+world&name=tag&name1=tag1...`.

The call in the perl script is: `$search_key = param('query')` does not contain the space or anything after it. $search_key = 'hello' only.

**Confusion**

It works fine when I use my own web server, apache, at localhost. But the problem arises when trying to put it online. The only differences in code are: (1)the url hyperlinks in the perl script - `search2011.cgi` vs. `multwordsearch.cgi` (Not an issue), (2)an intermediate loading page - `loading.cgi`, and (3)the url in the "action=" call in the HTML code:

Working:
`<form name="search_option" action="http://localhost/cgi-bin/multiwordsearch.cgi" method="get" onSubmit="return checkform(this);">`

vs.

Non-working:

```
<form name="search_option" action="/cgi-bin/loading.cgi" method="post" onSubmit="return checkform(this);">
        <h2><font color=forestgreen>Biomimetic Search</font></h2>
        <input type="text" name="query" size="40" />
```

**Also** Despite having "POST" it is still displaying `query=hello`!

I've tried the http... before /cgi-bin/, it did nothing. I tried `$search_key =~ s/ /+/` but it didn't do anything, so I know the space doesn't get that far. Also, the hyperlinks work correctly (ie. the whole URL: all name-value tags are printed after the query). I've tried increasing the size of the text.

If the search is 'hello+world' it works as it should, so the problem is something isn't interpreting the space correctly.

## Question

The problem is it truncates when coming from the form, either when the button is pressed, or just from the text field (or somewhere in cgi.pm).

Could this be a problem on my end? I realize there is limited info, but this is all that is different! Any ideas of what else to try?

Let me know if there is anything else you need.

Comment: The Perl looks fine. I've never had a problem sending spaces. Try commenting out the checkform() javascript call and see if it works. I suspect your problem lies there. Edit: Also in your first example the method is "GET" in the second example the method is "POST". It shouldn't matter but you might want to make it consistent to debug.

Comment: I tried `<form name="search_option" action="/cgi-bin/loading.cgi" method="post">` (eliminating the checkform) but it didn't work. Speaking of "POST" I still see `query=hello` is that right?

Comment: if you're using post you shouldn't see any of the query in the URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is your intermedia page which you discounted.
The one which worked was `multiwordsearch.cgi` and the one which doesn't work is `loading.cgi`. So I assume `loading.cgi` is the intermediate page.

This will definitely be what is causing the problem. I assume it is getting the params and then redirecting to `multiwordsearch.cgi`. This explains why your POSTed parameters to `loading.cgi` are ending up on the query string of `multiwordsearch.cgi`. So it obviously has a bug when building the redirect URL.

So I suggest you look at the URL building code in `loading.cgi`. Or post it here if you need help.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I will definitely look into it. My one correction is: The `loading.cgi` is the intermediate to another file: `search2011.cgi`. Which is a file that has the different url hyperlinks but is otherwise the same as `multisearch.cgi`.